# Use the same battery to power esp32, 3.3 volt relay and 3.3 volt water pump?

Tags: relay, esp32, fluid-pump

I have some basic questions about a waterpump circuit I'm making.

1. Can i use the same battery to power esp32, 3.3 volt relay and 3.3 volt water pump as in the following schematic? do i need a diode across the relay? inductor? (not sure i drew the gpio to the relay correctly, my realy has 3 inputs, V, gnd, and a signal pin from a gpio)

[image]

2. Is it possible to simply substitute the relay with a transistor as shown in the schematic? Also, is that how you insert a diode to protect the esp32 from back emf of pump?

[image]

Comment: 1. yes, use an smps DC-DC buck converter to turn battery voltage to 3.3v, which works well when a low battery is > 3.7v.  2. yes, if the transistor can handle the current. I would use an n-channel mosfet; they can handle more juice and they don't need that diode since there's one built-in. You could also use a darlington pnp like the tip120, which also has a built-in diode.

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the mosfet and darlington. But in that case won't the back emf go through the esp32?

Comment: i misread it, you are right, you don't need a diode to protect the _transistor_...

Comment: If your "relay" has three input pins, I suspect that it is really a relay module including a transistor or optocoupler so you can control the relay from an MCU output pin with no additional driver circuit.

Comment: Ah, it is indeed a relay module. What about the inductor? Would its back emf damage the relay?

Comment: Also having everything connected to the same battery would pose no risk for the back emf from inductor to go through mcu here (even if not through gpio since that, as you said is optocoupled)?